# Dynamic memory allocation for a matrix written as a struct

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need to allocate memory for a struct that contains a matrix:

```
typedef struct matrix{
int row;
int column;
int **data;
}MATRIX;
```

And i need to do all of it inside one separate function. I'm a bit confused because I'm not sure on how am I supposed to allocate memory for a matrix [row*column] that is inside of a struct that also contains numerical information about the row and column size. By my (obviously flawed) logic , that'd mean I'd need to allocate memory for the struct , input the info on row and column size, and then additionaly allocate memory for the matrix that's indside of a struct. I'm a bit confused by it, but this is what I've come up with so far:

```
int** alloc(MATRIX *array , int row , int column){

int i;

array->data = (int**)malloc(row * sizeof(int*));

for(i=0; i<br_red; i++){
    array->data[i] = (int*)malloc(column * sizeof(int));
}
return array->data;
}
```

And then inside of `main()` I do:

```
MATRIX *array = (MATRIX*)malloc(sizeof(MATRIX));
scanf("%d" , &array->row);
scanf("%d" , &array->column);
array->data = alloc(array , array->row , array->column);
```

And this code works properly, but my task is to completely allocate the memory for all data inside of one function of `MATRIX*` type (that returns fully allocated struct + matrix) without ever jumping back to `main()` to do the scanning.

Comment: You do not need to "do the scanning" to allocate the memory.  It looks like all you need to do is change the type of `alloc` so that it returns MATRIX *, move the `malloc(sizeof(MATRIX))` into the function, and return than value.

Comment: A one-dimensional array where you calculate the appropriate indices manually would be more efficient – for the price of less convenient addressing; you might provide helper functions for easier access, e. g. `int at(Matrix* m, size_t row, size_t column) { return m->data[row*m->column + column]; }`, similarly a `setAt` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `alloc` function to allocate a `MATRIX` internally and return it as the function result, like so:

```
MATRIX* alloc (int row , int column)
{
    MATRIX *array = (MATRIX *) malloc (sizeof (MATRIX));
    array->data = (int**)malloc(row * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        array->data[i] = (int*)malloc(column * sizeof(int));
    return array;
}
```

Your `main` then becomes:

```
int row, column;
scanf("%d" , &row);
scanf("%d" , &column);
MATRIX *array = alloc (row, column);
```

The casts before `malloc` are not necessary (in C), but they are harmless.